# Facebook page search in android SDK using GraphAPI

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get the search results based upon some keyword in android facebook sdk using Graph API.

**Example**: If i send a request as 'Arjun' and the result should like in json format. And if the result might contain People, Pages etc.,

Something Like in Facebook we have a search bar, when we type you get the results like People,Pages,books,apps etc.,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

to see what's possible concerning searching via the Graph API. Generally, you have to specify the object type you want to search upon. So, it's not comparable to the search functionality on facebook.com.